# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Autowiring bean with health actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am using spring boot actuator by implementing `HealthIndicator`.
I face issue while autowiring `AmazonSQSAsync` bean.

My code snippet:

```
@Component
public class HealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {  

    @Autowired
    AmazonSQSAsync _amazonSQSAsync;

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down()
              .withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    public int check() {
        // Your logic to check health
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Error:

> "message":"Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'HealthCheck': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field '_amazonSQSAsync';

Comment: Where do you declare the `AmazonSQSAsync` bean?

Comment: it is in aws library. I am not declaring it anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't automatically become a part of your Spring context. You need to provide an instance for `@Autowired` to inject. That's usually done by defining a bean in your configuration class, using the `@Bean` annotation.

Comment: After further debugging, come to know that there are cyclic dependency which is throwing this error. Lazy annotation while autowiring works for me. BDW thanks @nbrooks